# Is possible to assign a value to a variable conditionally in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, environment-variables

is it possible to assign a value to a variable depending of the result of a conditioning?

For example: I have the variables below:

```vb
Public legal
Public orphans
Public transfer_share
Public internet
Public xborder
```

I would like to increment each variable with the value returned from a `myFunction` but without a `if` statement or `select case`.

I think it would be possible if I consider a variable like an object.

Example of what I would like to replace:

```vb
Sub incrementVariable(myFunction as string)
If myfunction = "legal" then
    legal = legal + 2
ElseIf myFunction = "orphans" then
    orphans = orphans + 2
...
Else
    xborder = xborder + 2
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: No `Eval()` function in Excel... you may use public collection instead of separate variables and public string constants for number to name consistency...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the variables and their values:

```
Option Explicit

Public myDict As Dictionary

Sub InitializeDict()
    Set myDict = New Dictionary

    With myDict
        .Add "legal", 0
        .Add "orphans", 0
        .Add "transfer_share", 0
        .Add "internet", 0
        .Add "xborder", 0
    End With

End Sub

Sub incrementVariable(myFunction As String)
    If myDict.Exists(myFunction) Then
        myDict(myFunction) = myDict(myFunction) + 2
    End If
End Sub

Sub test()
    InitializeDict
    Debug.Print myDict("internet")
    incrementVariable ("internet")
    Debug.Print myDict("internet")
End Sub
```

To use dictionary object you need to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in Tools - References of VBA editor.